# How to get array of input value from dynamic table

Tags: php, jquery

I created a dynamic table of course list with 4 elements of input value each row.

```
<table id="tblCourse">
    <tr>
        <td>TXID</td>
        <td>CourseID</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Amount</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="TxID[0]"value=""  /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="CourseID[0]"value="C101"  /></td>            
        <td><input type="text" name="CourseDesc[0]"value="C#.NET"  /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Amount[0]"value="100.00"  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="TxID[1]"value=""  /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="CourseID[1]" value="C102" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="CourseDesc[1]" value="Php" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Amount[1]"value="200.00"  /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How do I get the input values with jQuery and pass to php array(txid,courseid,coursedesc, amt)? TIA

Comment: i would suggest , add a class like "table_input" to each input, and then use $('.table_input').serialize()  or serialization  to pass it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you named your input fields they are already PHP Arrays once sent to a php script, but it would be four arrays

```
$_POST['TxID'][] (1 and 2)
$_POST['CourseID'][] (1 and 2)
...
```

You have to name your fields a little different.

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="coursedata[1][TxID]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="coursedata[1][CourseID]" />C101</td>            
    <td><input type="text" name="coursedata[1][CourseDesc]" />C#.NET</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="coursedata[1][Amount]" />100.00</td>
</tr>
```

Of course you still need to count up for each new entry (1, 2, 3 ..).
That way you would get one array "$_POST['coursedata']" and $_POST['coursedata'][1] with the value of the input field.
I think that should work. Also, you should start counting with 0.

Comment: Starting with 0 array index the $_POST return Undefined index coursedata[0][CourseID]

``` if ( $_POST['courseData[0][CourseID]'])  echo  $_POST['courseData[0][CourseID]'];```

Comment: Code should be: $_POST['courseData'][0]['CourseID'] - look at the ''. You can also var_dump($_POST); to get a better look at the structure of the array.

Comment: Thanks this is the killer code : $_POST['courseData'][0]['CourseID'].